# Is there a way to query all branches associated with a GIT repository using AZ CLI extensions?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli

I am trying to code up a condition to check if a git repo has a specific branch.
If not, then create that branch.

I know the following commands via command line can be used to achieve this:

```
git branch
git checkout etc..
```

But I was wondering if there are any Azure Command line extensions to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [az repos ref list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos/ref?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_repos_ref_list). Use the filter option to search branches like "heads/your_path" (example on [rest API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#refs-heads))

Example:

```
az devops login --org "https://dev.azure.com/<your_org>"
Token:

az repos ref list --org "https://dev.azure.com/your_org" -p TeamProject -r RepoName --filter heads/

[
  {
    "creator": {
      "descriptor": "------",
      "directoryAlias": null,
      "displayName": "------",
      "id": "0f98bf70-30c3----",
      "imageUrl": "----",
      "inactive": null,
      "isAadIdentity": null,
      "isContainer": null,
      "isDeletedInOrigin": null,
      "profileUrl": null,
      "uniqueName": "-------",
      "url": "-------"
    },
    "isLocked": null,
    "isLockedBy": null,
    "name": "refs/heads/dev",
    "objectId": "4734085d73703e88ae39-----",
    "peeledObjectId": null,
    "statuses": null,
    "url": "-----"
  },
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helps. I can get the branch names using this. Do you know if I can create a fresh branch using this as well? For example: I see this command. az repos ref create. I am not a git expert and I am confused what the refs/heads/ is before the name of a branch. Would I still have to provide refs/heads while creating branch? Can you give an example for that as well? Thank you

Comment: @Rishabh to create a branch, you have to know the base object id. As an example, create a new branch based on master. Find the master branch with `az repos ref list` and the filter `heads/master`. Then use `az repos ref create` with a new name (like 'heads/dev2') and `objectId` from the master branch.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I am creating a git repo in ADO using the 'az repos create' command and I am trying to read the base object id. But it doesn't exist until the master branch exists. How do I create the repo and at the same time initialize it with a README.md or something? Can this be done without a git add, commit and push?

Comment: The Rest API tries to create initial commits through pushes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#initial-commit-(create-a-new-branch). But it does not exist in az cli. Try to set object id with "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" like in the rest API example.